# Are template types optional to use?

Tags: c++

Assume the following code:

```
template<typename T>
   void print(T in){
   std::cout << in << std::endl;
}
```

Both of the following can be used:

```
print(5);
print<int>(5);
```

So are the types optional or is there a reason for having them?

Comment: The point is to have deduction take place. So then `print(5)` and `print(5L)` will call respectively `print<int>` and `print<long>`. Mind you there are cases in which you want to manually specify the type.

Comment: @DeiDei This is not a pick on you but on what I feel is a little bit of a crack in the beauty of the language itself. "Mind you there are cases "... 

Spot on!

Answer (score 8):

There is a mechanism called template argument deduction. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction):

> In order to instantiate a function template, every template argument
>   must be known, but not every template argument has to be specified.
>   When possible, the compiler will deduce the missing template arguments
>   from the function arguments. This occurs when a function call is
>   attempted, when an address of a function template is taken, and in
>   some other contexts: [...]

In your example the compiler can deduce the template argument `T` because `5` is an `int`. Hence `void print<int>(int in)` is called.

> So are the types optional or is there a reason for having them?

Sometimes you still need to write the template arguments explicitly. For example if you want some conversion to happen you could call

```
print<double>(5);
print<int>(5.3);  // prints 5
```

> Does the same hold true for template classes?

Up to C++17 it was common to have function templates to create instances of class templates. Look at [`std::make_pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) as an example. Without it there was no way to ommit the template arguments

```
auto x = std::pair(1,2);          // before c++17: error missing template arguments
auto x = std::pair<int,int>(1,2); // OK
auto x = std::make_pair(1,2);     // OK deduces std::make_pair<int,int>
```

Since C++17 there is [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) which allows you to write:

> ```
> std::pair p(2, 4.5);     // deduces to std::pair<int, double> p(2, 4.5);
> ```

Comment: So it's unnecessary to have them for functions then, and I suppose it would work like an overloaded function? Does the same hold true for template classes?